# Extracting datapoint from mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table within MySQL which is being used to store user session information across a fleet of instances. The structure of the table is pretty simple, with 6 fields.

Item: 37824

Timestamp: 2014-10-30 23:01:41

Active: 14

Idle: 2

Total: 16

Server:

The metrics are collected every 5 minutes.

I have a query which pulls the SUM of one of the metrics for the past 5 minutes.

```
select SUM(metric_activeSessions) from metrics_tbl WHERE metric_timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

I want to build a chart from these metrics, using one of the many great libraries available, but yet to be determined.

I would like the chart to show the SUM of a given metric every over a period of 60 minutes, at 5 minute intervals.

```
- 09:00 : 12
- 09:05 : 15
- 09:10 : 18
- 09:15 : 21
- 09:20 : 28
```

I have no idea how to write an SQL query to collect information in that way and was hoping someone out there may be able to help me out.

Thank you in advance for any ideas,

Cheers,
Mitch

Comment: Well you have the query alreadym running every 5 minutes. What's the issue?

Comment: The query returns the SUM for the 5 minutes precessing NOW(), but in order to dynamically build a chart of a given metric over the past 60 minutes, I need to be able to return the SUM for every 5 minute block prior at the time the query is run. So, if I run the report at 10:00 am for example, I would like the query to return SUM values for the intervals 09:00-09:05-09:10 ... right up to 10:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `metric_timeStamp` is formatted as a mysql timestamp, try something like this..

```
SELECT SUM(metric_activeSessions), MAX(metric_timeStamp) as max_time, MIN(metric_timeStamp) as min_time,
FROM metrics_tbl 
WHERE metric_timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
GROUP BY unix_timestamp(metric_timeStamp) div 300
```

Use that as a starting point. I'm eating ice cream right now so I can't run this myself, but that's the general idea.

**Edit:** fixed syntax issue

**Edit 2:** I was grouping by 10 minutes. Changed it to 5 minutes

**Edit 3:** If your rows contain a running total, then change

```
SUM(metric_activeSessions)
```

to

```
MAX(metric_activeSessions)
```

in the query above.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!The response seems a little off though.

`5619, 5907, 6184, 6455, 6697. I know these numbers are not correct for the past hour. It's incrementing something, can't quite work out what.

Comment: If you create a table in sqlfiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com, with some of your sample data, I will get you a more precise sql statement

Comment: Hey FoxyGen, here is sqlfiddle with some dummy data in ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9f6f/1

Comment: It looks like
`SELECT SUM(metric_activeSessions), MAX(metric_timeStamp) as max_time, MIN(metric_timeStamp) as min_time,
FROM metrics_tbl 
WHERE metric_timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
GROUP BY unix_timestamp(metric_timeStamp) div 300` 
does the trick! Thanks dude.

Comment: Just trying to figure out how to do that :)

Comment: Big green tick! Thank FoxyGen.